# Clone Linux system preserving/reconfiguring network interfaces

Tags: linux, clone, network-interface

**The problem**

When I clone a Linux OS on a different device (but exact same architecture), the ethernet interfaces will be called differently (e.g. device A: eth0, eht1; device B: eht2, eth3). It's difficult create an OS image with preconfigured network interfaces

**Why I need this**

I have a couple of eth interfaces. The first one (physically first; let's say the one on the left on the case) is for LAN and relies on DHCP. The second one (say the one on the right) is for a device with a fixed IP; eth on system must have a fixed IP in the same pool. When cloning the system I want the eth interfaces to be correctly configured on new systems.

**Tried so far**

I made 2 main test, one with an embedded device (OS on SD), one with an actual PC (OS on HDD).

With the embedded device I cloned the configured OS with dd on a second SD and connected said SD to a second system. First system has the network configuration, for eth17 interface (single network interface system), on /etc/network/interfaces with a static IP. The second system mappend the interface on eht18, so configuration on /etc/network/interfaces got ignored.

With the PC system I had 2 interfaces, eth0 and eth1, one in DHCP, the second with fixed IP. I cloned the system with Clonezilla on a second system. On this second system the interfaces became eth1 and eth2; again, the configuration got screwed.

**What to do?**

Is there a way to have the new system to name the eth intarface like the first one did, so configurations on /etc/network/interfaces will be still valid?

Otherwise, is there a way to guess how the interfaces got scrambled and reconfigure them on startup? I suppose the problem here is to know the relationship between OS eth interfaces and physical eth interfaces.

Comment: "is there a way to guess how the interfaces got scrambled?" You should probably get familiar with the concept of [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/). Note the link leads to an obsolete document (that explains the concept though).

Comment: Read the document. Thanks for the hint. Looks like systemd is the init process that will map eth based on topology/bios info/... In this very moment I'm using MX Linux, that is not systemd based (although systemd compatible). I'm trying to boot it with systemd to see if the interfaces names will change on a system (and persist to a new one with exact same architecture). Will update